# Laravel Query builder equivalent to SQL query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

I have two table Country and state and SQL query for State is

```
select state.id,state.state_name,Country.Country_name from country,state where state.country=country.id
```

This query is working fine, i want to convert this into laravel query builder

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir did not understand syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```php
DB::table('country')
    ->select('state.id', 'state.state_name', 'country.country_name')
    ->join('state', 'state.country', '=', 'country.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: which table name will come for XX and YY,  DB::table('xx') , join('yy',

Comment: In this query you can interchange `country` and `state`, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In controller function:

```
DB::table('country')->leftjoin('state', function ($join) {
            $join('state', 'state.country', '=', 'country.id');})->get();
```

In controller import DB facades:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```